# vb.net external manipulation commands

Tags: vb.net, integration

I tried to find this but I'm not exactly sure how to search for it or if it would even be possible. I'm trying to integrate a program I wrote with a commercial app, the commercial app has the ability to call an external program with a command and pass it the data that I want to capture.

I want to be able to get the currently open instance (or whichever responds first in the case of multiple instances) and send it the information directly and have it perform a function based on that information, I don't want to have to open a new instance.

I know one of my options is to drop a text file with the info and then have my program watch for it and parse it once found but if I can do a more direct communication I'd rather do that.

all it needs to do is fill a text box and run a function seems simple enough, and all I need is a point in the wright direction or some search terms that would pull up pertinent results. I'd like to understand how it works instead of just having someone write the code for me.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have the source-code for the 'commercial app'?

Comment: The most important part was left out. What is the app you're trying to integrate with? Some commercial apps have an API you can use but everyone of them are different so without knowing what the app is, the only thing I can say is that you need to search the name of the app and "API". If they have anything, you should find examples.

Comment: The program I want to integrate with is my own. I have not written any API's in that's what I'm trying to figure out. The commercial program is landesk it has the ability to run a command line and pass information about a computer to it. I want to send that information to my program and have it perform a function based on what it receives.

Comment: It's not completely clear whether you want to pass info from the commercial app to your app or the other way around.  It's also not clear if the app that is being called has to return data to the calling app.  Once we get this straightened out, we can discuss options for exchanging data.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear. LANDesk can run (from within it's console) a command line example "cmd /c ping <ComputerName> -t" and landesk will substitute that <ComputerName> with the name of the computer you are focusing on, I want to be able to use that to some how run a function from within my application that gathers extra information on the computer name that was supplied by landesk so like "myProgram.exe -Get:<ComputerName>" or something to that nature, But I don't want to to start a new instance of my program, I want it to use the currently running instance.